# jQuery change Href based on li class

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML Structure:**

```
<li class="page_item page-item-7 page_item_has_children">
<a href="http://localhost/myproject/parent/">Parent</a>
<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
<ul class="children">
<li class="page_item page-item-9">
<a href="http://localhost/myproject/parent/Child One/">Child One</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-10">
<a href="http://localhost/myproject/parent/Child Two/">Child Two</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('li.page_item_has_children a[href*="/parent/"]').attr("href", "#");
});
```

The above code works and changes the URL for `Parent` but along with it changes the URL for its `Children` too. So the resulting html is

**Output:**

```
<li class="page_item page-item-7 page_item_has_children">
<a href="#">Parent</a>
<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
<ul class="children">
<li class="page_item page-item-9">
<a href="#">Child One</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-10">
<a href="#">Child One</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

How can I change only the `Parent` href and not its pertaining children elements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use immediate **[child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)** `>`.

> Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('li.page_item_has_children > a').attr("href", "#");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this : You need to use `>` for finding direct child

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('li.page_item_has_children > a[href*="/parent/"]').attr("href", "#");
});
```